# Trying to implement a nested If Else statement inside REACTJS. Get error 0 is not a function

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to implement an if else statement in react. I am new with this language and everytime load the app get the error 0 is not a function. In few words I need that statement if is loading o does not have data has to show loading... else if the value of the props is 0 has to conditional render the rest. Could anyone help me please?Thanks in advance

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Stake from './stake';

class FetchRandomBet extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            loading: true,
            bet: null,
            value: this.props.value
        };
    }


    async componentDidMount() {
        const url = "http://localhost:4000/";
        const response = await fetch(url);
        const data = await response.json();

        this.setState({
            loading: false,
            bet: data.bets
        });
    }
    render() {
        const { valueProp: value } = this.props;
        console.log(value)
        if (this.state.loading) {
            return <div>loading..</div>;
        }
        if (!this.state.bet) {
            return <div>did not get data</div>;
        }
        return (
            < div >
                {
                    this.state.loading || !this.state.bet ? (
                        <div>loading..</div>
                    ) : value == 0(
                        <div className="bet-list">
                            <ol>
                                <p>NAME</p>
                                {
                                    this.state.bet.map(post => (
                                        <li key={post.id}>
                                            {post.name}
                                        </li>
                                    ))
                                }
                            </ol>
                            <ul>
                                <p>ODDS</p>
                                {
                                    this.state.bet.map(post => (
                                        <li key={post.id}>
                                            {post.odds[4].oddsDecimal}
                                            <div className="stake-margin">
                                                <Stake />
                                            </div>
                                        </li>
                                    ))
                                }
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    )
                }
            </div >
        );
    }
}

export default FetchRandomBet;
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow. Can you reproduce this error online in sandbox?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

let's add the `&&` operator after after equating:

```
value === 0 && (
```

Comment: Could you explain me why I should add &&?Thanks

Comment: This is because the entry suggests that JS should execute a function called 0.
The && operator is similar to the `?` operator (if), except that it doesn't require the `:` operator (else) after it.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Could you tell me if there is any forum where I can learn this way of coding if els in react?

Comment: I think you should be interested in the React documentation itself: https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html